# Converting iTunes m3u file to be readable by mpd (special characters and encoding issue)

Tags: itunes, encoding, utf-8, mpd

I have generated a iTunes m3u file because it is easier to create specific playlist (with intelligent playlists). It needed a little conversion to replace ^M characters to newline, but now I have another problem.
In fact, mpd doesn't recognize the encoding of the file when there are special characters.

When I copy/paste what I have in my file I have:

```
cat -e test/1
extern/chanson francM-LM-'aise/Mickey 3D/La TreM-LM-^Bve/10 L' Homme Qui Suivait Les Nuages.mp3$
```

And the encoding that mpd can read for the same mp3 file:

```
cat -e test/2
extern/chanson franM-CM-'aise/Mickey 3D/La TrM-CM-*ve/10 L' Homme Qui Suivait Les Nuages.mp3$
```

I've tested various iconv encoding but I can find the correct one to create a readable file for mpd. Is there somebody who knows how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use iconv *on a Mac*.

Like this:

```
iconv -f utf8-mac -t utf-8 file > file2
```